# E11000 duplicate key error index: MongoDb unusual error

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I have a simple "users" collection inside which right now i have only 2 documents.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4ef8e1e41d41c87069000074"),
    "email_id": {
        "0": 109,
        "1": 101,
        "2": 64,
        "3": 97,

{
    "_id": ObjectId("4ef6d2641d41c83bdd000001"),
    "email_id": {
        "0": 109,
        "1": 97,
        "2": 105,
        "3": 108,
```

now if i try to create a new index with {unique: true} on email_id field, mongodb complaints me with "E11000 duplicate key error index: db.users.$email_id dup key: { : 46 }". I get same error even after specifying {dropDups: true}, however i don't think this is the case here, as both document have different email id's stored.

I am not sure what's going on here, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Full view of documents:**

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("4ef8e1e41d41c87069000074"),
"email_id": {
 "0": 109,
 "1": 101,
 "2": 64,
 "3": 97,
 "4": 98,
 "5": 104,
 "6": 105,
 "7": 110,
 "8": 97,
 "9": 118,
 "10": 115,
 "11": 105,
 "12": 110,
 "13": 103,
 "14": 104,
 "15": 46,
 "16": 99,
 "17": 111,
 "18": 109
 }
}
```

and

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("4ef6d2641d41c83bdd000001"),
"email_id": {
 "0": 109,
 "1": 97,
 "2": 105,
 "3": 108,
 "4": 115,
 "5": 102,
 "6": 111,
 "7": 114,
 "8": 97,
 "9": 98,
 "10": 104,
 "11": 105,
 "12": 110,
 "13": 97,
 "14": 118,
 "15": 64,
 "16": 103,
 "17": 109,
 "18": 97,
 "19": 105,
 "20": 108,
 "21": 46,
 "22": 99,
 "23": 111,
 "24": 109
 }
}
```

There are a couple of more fields like "display_name", "registered_since", etc which i have omitted from the display above (i don't think they have any role in the error thrown, if you still need them i can probably paste the entire documents here)

I am using [erlang mongodb driver](https://github.com/TonyGen/mongodb-erlang) for communication with my mongo instance. All fields as can be seen are saved as binary bytes, thats why you see such weird email_id in document.

Note: Binary byte format is not forced by my code logic, i very much pass string email_id inside my bson documents, but i always end up seeing my data as binary bytes. (Probably because how erlang mongodb driver is written, i didn't really investigate on this, since my find(), find_one() and other queries works as expected even with fields saved as binary bytes)

Edit: > db.users.findOne()

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4ef6d2641d41c83bdd000001"),
"email_id" : [
    109,
    97,
    105,
    108,
    115,
    102,
    111,
    114,
    97,
    98,
    104,
    105,
    110,
    97,
    118,
    64,
    103,
    109,
    97,
    105,
    108,
    46,
    99,
    111,
    109
],
"display_name" : [
    65,
    98,
    104,
    105,
    110,
    97,
    118,
    43,
    83,
    105,
    110,
    103,
    104
],
"provider" : [
    106,
    97,
    120,
    108,
    46,
    105,
    109
],
"provider_id" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Why your email looks so strange?

Comment: Are the values for `email_id` actually subdocuments indexed by string keys which are integers? Or are they arrays, and this is just the representation of them in your programming language? Also, which language are you using?

Comment: You need to provide more information. It appears the documents you provided are incomplete? Does 'email_id' have more than 3 elements? Perhaps element 46 is duplicated in the two documents?  When/how are you adding an index? Is this in a script or in the mongo shell? As @Sergei Tulentsev says, you should provide a complete view of the documents. And the smallest set of code you can that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @chakram88 i tried creating my indexes are inserting two documents in the collection. I have tried creating indexes using both mongo shell and rockmongo admin panel with same error. I am not sure why really actually my email_id in documents show up as above. My bson document while inserting inside the collection is as simple as {email_id, "me@mail.com}.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `db.users.findOne()` from the mongo shell? I'm still not sure if Mongo is treating these as arrays or as subdocuments.

Comment: as @dcrosta says, how mongoDB is storing the email seems to be key. If the binary representation is seen as subdocuments, there are several of the 'keys' which duplicate between the two documents you display (although the 'key{:46}' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When MongoDB indexes an array field, it actually indexes the individual elements in the array. This is to efficiently support queries looking for a particular element of an array, like:

```
db.users.find({email_id: 46})
```

Since this `email_id` (46) exists in both documents, there are duplicate keys in your unique index.

I'm not sure why you would get this error if you have `dropDups: true` set... can you show a code sample with how you're invoking `createIndex`? You should also try `dropDups: 1`, as MongoDB erroneously treats `1` and `true` differently in this context (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4562).

Comment: well i think this indeed is the case. dropDups work from mongo shell, it failed from mongorock admin panel. I read erlang bson document which says: "Caution, a string() will be interpreted as an array of integers. You must supply strings as utf8 binary, see below." - in this case i cannot save my email_id as strings, since i want email_id field to be unique as a whole string, no per character wise uniqueness required. This is really messy which i think comes from erlang mongodb driver, if i pass my email_id field as an atom, it is preserved as complete string n not char wise array as above.

Comment: Ah, I see. So these are actually strings which are wrongly encoded as arrays of integers? In that case, you should be sure to do what the docs are recommending regarding UTF8 binary so that they are saved as strings in MongoDB. Also, which driver are you using?

Comment: i am using erlang mongodb driver by tony (https://github.com/TonyGen/mongodb-erlang) ... indeed all one needs to do is pass strings as utf8 binaries if they must be saved as strings ... if passed as erlang lists, they will be stored as shown above in snippets, which will lead to unique key creation errors. I think this question can be marked as close. It was more about reading the docs carefully, and pass strings as utf8 binaries

Comment: OK. I don't know much about Erlang, but it sounds like you have to use the [`utf()` function](http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/bson/bson.html#utf8-1) to convert your string to a UTF-8 string for storage in MongoDB, otherwise the driver will store it as an array of code points (i.e. ints). Once you do this, it will be a scalar value, not an array, in mongo and you'll be able to add your unique index.

Comment: Thanks every1, just for an update, if you are using erlang + mongodb, simply make sure all document keys are saved as erlang binary term, so that mongodb pick them up as mentioned in their docs. Also it's a good (recommended) practice to pass erlang messages and params in binary (between procs) where ever you can (possibly always)...

Comment: thx for mentioning that 1 and true are not handled the same way had a same problem with php, used 1 but it only works with true

Answer (score 0):

For others having this problem, check your mongo version with `db.version()`. If you are running Mongo 3 and are trying to use dropDups to clear duplicates, it will fail and give you this error.